# RSpec, is there a way to flag known errors as warnings?

Tags: rspec3

Consider the case where an RSpec test uncovers an error.  I write the PR but I want the test to continue.  I could comment the expect() but I don't want to loose track of the failure.

Is there a way to raise a warning rather than a failure?  Something like expect_warn(...,'PR0032')

When the PR is fixed I want to go back and replace with the original expect()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can mark specs as [pending or skipped](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples).

Comment: Pending or skipped steps show up as pending.  Pro: Such steps are flagged in the final report with a reason i.e. PR number  Con: The rest of the step isn't executed.